# how to send header(token) to webservice in swift

Tags: swift, web-services, token

I have a code to send data to a web service that supposedly sends the token, but apparently it is wrong because the token does not reach the server, I hope you can help me. My code is as follows:

```
let token = "eyJ0enssnsuwew"

let url = URL(string: "http://webservice")
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It isn't clear what you are asking. Do you get an error message?

Comment: The error message is from the server, and this is: {"status":false,"message":"Error de token"}
that does it mean that the token is not coming to the server,
my question is why?